# boost::optional<T&> vs T*

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

I'm trying to understand when is the right time to use some of the structures that come with `boost` and had a question regarding the use of `boost::optional` with a reference.

Suppose I have the following class, using `boost::optional`:

```
class MyClass {
public:
   MyClass() {}

   initialise(Helper& helper) {
      this->helper = helper;
   }

   boost::optional<Helper&> getHelper() {
      return helper;
   }

private:
   boost::optional<Helper&> helper;
}
```

Why would I use the above instead of:

```
class MyClass {
public:
   MyClass() : helper(nullptr) {}

   initialise(Helper& helper) {
      this->helper = &helper;
   }

   Helper* getHelper() {
      return helper;
   }

private:
   Helper* helper;
}
```

They both convey the same intent, i.e. that `getHelper` could return `null`, and the caller still needs to test if a helper was returned.

Should you only be using `boost::optional` if you need to know the difference between 'a value', `nullptr` and 'not a value'?

Comment: boost::optional<T&> just wrapper of T*. Prefer T* than boost::optional<T&> due to boost::optional<T&> is weird in C++. T* has better readability

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Compared to a raw pointer, an optional reference may suggest that (1) pointer arithmetic is not used, and (2) ownership of the referent is maintained elsewhere (so `delete` will clearly not be used with the variable).

Comment: In Modern C++ a raw pointer should already suggest that ownership is maintained elsewhere.

Answer (score 20):

Great question, and John Zwinck's answer above is right. However, some people (e.g., many on the standardization committee), doubt whether these reasons are enough to justify the existence of `optional<T&>`, when `optional<T&>` can have such confusing semantics. Consider what should happen when you assign to one of these guys. Should it re-seat the reference (i.e., make it point to a different object), or assign through the reference, like a real `T&` does? A case can be made for either, which would cause confusion and subtle bugs. Support for `optional<T&>` was removed from the [proposal](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3672.html) that recently got accepted into the C++14.

In short, if you want to make your code portable to C++14's `std::optional`, prefer `T*` over `boost::optional<T&>`.