# Is it correct to return a raw pointer from a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, unique-ptr

**Question**: Is it correct to return a raw pointer from a unique_ptr if the raw pointer is only being used as a reference?

**Background**: For a challenge I'm starting to create a simple 2D game engine in my free time. I have a *Screen* base class, and a *ScreenManager* base class that each get derrived from.

The *Screen* would be used for things like Splash screens, Options Menus, and of course the ever important Game screen.

The *ScreenManager* base class will be used for (Vectorized, Stacked, etc.)  managers that can be specilized for the games needs.

**Details**: Currently my *Screen* class holds a raw pointer to the *ScreenManager* that is managing it. This is so, within the current screen, it can choose based on it's state, what new screen to push onto the manager next.

Stripped Down Sudo Code Examples
Screen Class

> ```
> class ScreenManager; //Forward Declaration
> class Screen {
> protected: ScreenManager* m_manager; // Ptr reference to manager
> public:
>     explicit Screen(ScreenManager *manager) : m_manager(manager){}
>
>     virtual void handleEvents(const event);
>     // Possibly call m_manager->changeScreen(newScreenUPtr)
>     virtual void update(const time, const window);
>     virtual void render(const time, window);
> }
> ```

ScreenManager Class

> ```
> class ScreenManager {
> // Implementation specific container of Screens
> private:
>     virtual void handleEvents(const event); // Call active screens handleEvents()
>     virtual void update(const time, const window); // Same, for update()
>     virtual void render(const time, window); // Same, for render()
> public:
>     virtual void changeScreen(unique_ptr<Screen> newScreen); 
> }
> ```

**Requery**: Is there a better way than taking a ScreenManager pointer into the Screen class, or am I doing it right?

Comment: [Somewhat relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536731/shared-ptr-is-to-weak-ptr-as-unique-ptr-is-to-what).

Comment: Who owns whom? Express "owns X of type Y" as `unique_ptr<Y> X`. Express "has a non-owning reference to X of type Y" as plain `Y* x`. If you have two things that presume to own each other, you are gonna have a bad time.

Comment: If it's non-owning, raw pointers are fine. (Or you can write something like the proposed [`observer_ptr`](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf), the World’s Dumbest Smart Pointer(TM), to make the non-owning-ness explicit.)

Comment: `virtual void changeScreen(unique_ptr<Screen> newScreen);` I'm pretty sure this won't compile; it requires `unique_ptr<Screen>` to be copied, but `unique_ptr` can't be copied. If you want `changeScreen` to claim ownership, take `unique_ptr<Screen>&& newScreen` and move from it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Taking a move only type by value is not a problem, as long as you pass an r-value. Only when you try to pass an l-value to it will there be an error.

Comment: I think what you are doing is exactly right. In my opinion there is nothing wrong with using raw pointers as long as they are managed by a smart pointer/pointer manager in the correct scope to ensure their lifespan is correct. If that is true then you never have to delete a raw pointer and you can safely use them within the scope/frame throughout which their life-time is guaranteed.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This is just sudo code. I have a working solution, compiles and runs fine. Just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: @Galik That's what I was thinking initially, The raw pointer is only used as a reference, and it still actively managed in the unique_ptr once it goes out of scope. So no leaks.

Comment: @BFritz well the alternative, as far as I can see, is passing a around reference to the unique_ptr but I am not really sure what advantage that gives over a raw pointer.

Comment: Yea, @BenjaminLindley and Igor: the new way of doing things is “Pass by value to sink object types”.  I can't find the talk that goes into that in details but it's discussed here ( http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning#c635143842141373374 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a *back pointer* pattern, right?  A points to B with ownership, and B points back at its A with no ownership.

The fully robust way would be to use shared_ptr and weak_ptr.  If this is single threaded, you can document the rules at the parent pointer declaration, and note that the unique_ptr causes B to be destroyed first when A is destroyed.  So that's safe, **if** you don't misuse the pointers or change the code later and alter the situation.  So, comments and good names are important.  Agreed, the compiler can't enforce all possible misuses and wipe your nose too.

In real-world code, you can count on someone adding a feature later and perturbing anything that's “OK because it's all correct”.

Comment: The real code is documented, perhaps too thoroughly. I like the shared/weak ptr concept. I'm relatively new to programming concepts and terminology. I'll look up "back pointer" and do some tests on my dev branch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the `ScreenManager` outlives the contained `Screen`s then I think you are doing it right.

It is possible you might want to break your cyclic dependency between `Screen` and `ScreenManager` by introducing a more stable interface, e.g `IScreenManager` but it's fine as it is.