# Is typename required or not here?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, typename

Consider the code:

```
#include <memory>

template <class T, class Deleter = std::default_delete<T>>
class unique_ptr_wrapper: public std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>
{
public:
    using typename std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::unique_ptr;
    operator T* () const {return this->get();}
};

int main()
{
    unique_ptr_wrapper<int> upw{new int{42}};
}
```

g++5.1 compiles it fine, although clang++ complains

> error: typename is allowed for identifiers only

I agree that we don't have an identifier here, so probably `typename` is not required. But is it actually forbidden? Is the compiler required to at least emit a diagnostic?

**EDIT** The code is compiled fine without `typename` by both g++ and clang++.

---

**UPDATE** It seems to be a g++ bug, I reported it [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66350).

Comment: In the interest of completing the matrix, does this compile on *both* toolchains *without* `typename` ?

Comment: `unique_ptr` is an identifier. But here it names a constructor, not the type, so `typename` is inappropriate.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, it compiles on both without `typename`.

Comment: @aschepler That's what I believe too, so it looks like a g++ bug (unless no diagnostic required).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[class.inhctor]/p1, emphasis mine:

> A *using-declaration* (7.3.3) that **names a constructor** implicitly
>   declares a set of *inheriting constructors*.

A constructor is not a type.

[temp.res]/p3-4:

> 3 When a *qualified-id* is intended to refer to a type that is not a
>   member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1) and its
>   *nested-name-specifier* refers to a dependent type, it shall be prefixed by the keyword `typename`, forming a typename-specifier. If
>   the *qualified-id* in a *typename-specifier* does not denote a type,
>   the program is ill-formed.
>
> 4 If a specialization of a template is instantiated for a set of
>   *template-arguments* such that the *qualified-id* prefixed by `typename` does not denote a type, the specialization is ill-formed.
>   The usual qualified name lookup (3.4.3) is used to find the
>   *qualified-id* even in the presence of `typename`.

[class.qual]/p2:

> In a lookup in which function names are not ignored and the
>   *nested-name-specifier* nominates a class `C`:
>
> - if the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier*, when looked up in `C`, is the *injected-class-name* of `C` (Clause 9), or
> - in a *using-declaration* (7.3.3) that is a *member-declaration*, if the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier* is the same as
>     the *identifier* or the *simple-template-id*’s *template-name* in the
>     last component of the *nested-name-specifier*,
>
> the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class `C`.

Applying the "usual qualified name lookup" rules found in [class.qual], `std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::unique_ptr` names the constructor. It does not denote a type. Therefore, by the above quote from [temp.res], the program is ill-formed (with a diagnostic required).

In other words, this appears to be a GCC bug (though Clang's error message could use some improvement too).

Comment: Also, 7.3.3 [namespace.udecl]/19 says "If a _using-declaration_ uses the keyword typename and specifies a dependent name (14.6.2), the name introduced by the _using-declaration_ is treated as a _typedef-name_ (7.1.3)." so if it means anything then `using typename ...` should declare a typedef, not inheriting constructors.